# SQLite database crash due to reopen already closed object

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have my DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "name";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

private Context mTempCtx = null;

private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    mTempCtx = context;
}


public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (null == dbHelper) {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }
    return dbHelper;
} 
...
```

My main activity with tabs

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

// private AdView mAdView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .getWritableDatabase();

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ...
```

and fragment in first tab

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Cursor cur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
            TABLE.CONTENT_URI, TABLE.PROJECTION, null, null, null);
```

This query makes my

```
06-18 08:21:05.854: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: ...
```

This code works on 4.2.2 and 4.3, 4.4, but I get crash on 4.1 and 2.3.7. For now after reading few tutorials and questions here it still didnt work for me.

Comment: show more code which is written inside `onCreateView()`!

Comment: There is only inflater, get ListView object from and setHasOptionsMenu(true); more

Answer (score 0):

if You want to do some database operation after db.close ,then you must call db.getWritableDatabase().

Comment: If I add DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase(); to onCreateView in fragment I still get the same error

Comment: for every db operation you need to call db.getWritableDatabase() and close(db.close) after process finished.

Comment: I know, but still, nothing happens. Why its work on 4.2.2 and crash on 4.1?